# Android - Phone storage full

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace. Every time I try to install a new App I get a message saying my internal memory is full (the SD card has plenty of room). The phone has 180MB of internal storage. I counted the memory that all my apps should take and it came out to 50MB so something is taking up 130MB and I don't know what that is. I rooted my device and moved all the apps that could be moved to the SD card. It still says that I have only 20 free MB. I was wondering if there are any apps out there that can tell me what is taking up all my memory. If not is there any way to programmatically map out the internal storage of the device? Does Android block access to this storage, or can I view it from my computer in any way?

Comment: There are some applications like "folder mount" that can help with that. Also you can move some apps to the SD card to empty more space.

Comment: I moved all possible apps to SD card only system apps that can't be moved are still on the phone.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt noticed that in the initial post. Another option is to root the phone and check out which app consumes how much space, with Titanium backup

Comment: You can also use this app, I think it does not require rooted phone https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage

Comment: I used folder mount to analyze partition sizes and it shows that /data is almost full. How do I empty it?

Comment: What are the data...maybe you browser pictures from facebook/dropbox and it caches them

Comment: `/data` is the user data partition (rather `/data/data`), i.e. where all user-installed apps go, and all data of all apps. You can empty it by a factory-reset, but that's unlikely what you want to do :) Rather check the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) to get a start. py_script already suggested "folder mount", which is the right direction: pure app2sd only moves *parts of the apps*, but doesn't touch their data etc.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Disk Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) to show simply where are the octets.